# Complex numbers with conjugate multiplication - field or ...?

Tags: complex-numbers

I could have sworn that when we learned about complex numbers in signals and systems that they form a field in (at least) two ways, depending on multiplication, which is most intuitively described in polar coordinates:

Normal multiplication adds the arguments' phases, while conjugate multiplication subtracts them.

But, whereas (scalar) phase addition is associative, subtraction is only left associative.

So what algeraic structure does $\mathbb C$ under complex conjugation form?

Comment: If I use $z\times w$ to mean conjugate multiplication, and $zw$ to mean ordinary multiplication, you are talking about $z\times w=z\overline w$, right?

Comment: Yes $zw$ versus $z \overline w$

Comment: It does not subtract them, it adds their opposites. Unless you actually talk about $z\cdot \bar{w}$. In which case your are looking at an inner product space.

Comment: @julien, can you explain what you mean by 'opposites'? conjugate multiplication is not commutative - it only take the complex conjugate of the 2nd argument.

Comment: I'm lost. I simply mean: if $z=re^{i\theta}$ and $w=\rho e^{i\phi}$, then $\overline{zw}=r\rho e^{-i(\theta+\phi)}$. But I'm afraid I misunderstood something. I think you talk about $z\cdot\bar{w}$, and not $\overline{zw}$.

Comment: In your last comment you may have accidentally overlined both $z$ and $w$ - only the 2nd argument should be conjugated. The right-hand side should be $z\overline{w}=r\rho e^{i(\theta-\phi)}$

Comment: @julien, then...?

Comment: Hello. Then what?

Comment: Do my subsequent comments resolve your: "It does not subtract them, it adds their opposites"?

Comment: no it doesn't. yhy are you using plural 'their opposites'? Only one of the 2 is conjugated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The map $\mathbb C\times \mathbb C\to\mathbb C$ defined by $(z,w)\mapsto z\overline w$ is the standard inner product on $\mathbb C$.   Thought of in this way, it isn't a multiplication in a ring, but rather it is thought of in the same way that an inner product on any other complex vector space $V$ defines a map $V\times V\to \mathbb C$ with certain properties.

But if we think of $\mathbb C$ together with "conjugate multiplication" and ordinary addition as operations on $\mathbb C$, then multiplication is nonassociative (and noncommutative), but still distributive over addition, hence $\mathbb C$ with this structure is a nonassociative ring. It still has some nice properties, like a *right* (but no left, thanks Hurkyl) multiplicative identity, multiplicative inverses for all nonzero elements, and cancellation.

I don't know if it falls under a particularly well studied class of nonassociative rings, but there are books written on nonassociative rings and algebras where you might find something.  Like $\mathbb C$ with its ordinary multiplication, the complex conjugation operation $\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$ still has an important role, with its relation to multiplication given by $\overline{z\times w}=\overline w\times \overline z$.

Comment: I do believe you only have a right identity.

Comment: You're right, thanks for catching my careless error.

Comment: But now that I've said that, there is a weird sort of left identity formed by left-multiplying by 1, and then again by 1.

Comment: @Hurkyl: Yes, or generally $z\times (1\times w)=zw$.  Interesting that conjugation becomes left multiplication by $1$.